# PHP image grid using table

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving images and want to display a grid of two rows and 3 images in each row, essentially 6 images in each page. For simplicity I am using a table for this. My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM photos
            WHERE user = $userid
            LIMIT $start, $end;";

$result = $mysql->query($sql);

echo "<table><tr>";
while( $record = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo "
            <td><img src='$record[name]' width='300' height='300' /></td>
         ";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

As mentioned I want a grid of 6 images per page at 3 images per row. Each cell will have a distinct image. The images right now appear horizontally. How can I achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a counter. When your record iterations reaches that counter (ie after image 3 is printed), then start a new table row.

```
$x=0;
while( $record = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $x++;

    echo "
            <td><img src='$record[name]' width='300' height='300' /></td>
         ";


    if($x == 3){
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }

}
```

Comment: totally missed that! Thanks!